# An if comparison is not executed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ValMail() {
        var txt = document.getElementById("<%= Email.ClientID%>");
        "<%mailFormat(Email.Text)%>"
        if ('<%= mType%>' != 'false') {
            txt.value = '';
            txt.focus();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Which I calling it from an asp.net page control:

```
<asp:TextBox  ID="Email" runat="server" TabIndex="4" CssClass="textEntry" 
    CausesValidation="True" OnClientBlur="ValMail()" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:TextBox>
```

The `OnClientBlur` call the script just fine (I follow by debugging) comes in the line `if` but not goes further.

The `mType` is a `Public Shared` declared in the code behind; and it is very certain that has the value of `false`. Can I have an assistance on that? 
Code always dismissed from `'<%= mType%>'`

Comment: `"it is very certain that has the value of false"` - Can you share the rendered client-side code to be even more certain?  Instead of examining the server-side code and assuming what it's going to look like on the client, examine the actual client-side code.

Comment: If `mType` Contain the string 'false', then `('false' != 'false') === false`. That mean you will never enter the if...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon What do you propose for it?

Comment: You are testing that the variable it is NOT false, so the block is not executed because the variable, as you say, has the value 'false'. If you want the block to be executed then you need `<%= mType %> === 'false'`. Don't forget to use the triple equal sign, as the double in JS has a different meaning.

Comment: @mastazi I did the change and I test it nop! it's the same result

Comment: How the '<%= mType%>' is rendered in the View source of your browser ?

Comment: @user3041160 rendered as `false or true`

Comment: try this : if (<%= mType%>) { ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*: the suggested solution was to use the RequiredFieldValidator and the RegularExpressionValidator in order to validate the e-mail address, which is a better suited approach for ASP.NET WebForms validation. The basic flaw in the original code was that it was testing client-side for the validity of the e-mail address using the value that the server had generated (and so not the actual e-mail that the user had entered, which was always ignored). */end of update*

Perhaps you could paste the rendered javascript here, without the server-side logic. Only what the browser sees.

Also, is it possible that this line:

```
    "<%mailFormat(Email.Text)%>"
```

is lacking a trailing semicolon?

Comment: I put it but gives me the same

Comment: Like I said, it would help a lot if you would provide the rendered javascript that the browser is actually seeing. Actually, now that I'm seeing it again, the "<%mailFormat(Email.Text)%" is, eventually, just a string as far as Javascript is concerned, right? So that's not even a valid statement?

Comment: Well that line is executed just fine; the `"<%mailFormat(Email.Text)%"` is a call to the code behind and it is a `sub` which gives to the `public shared mType`the value `true or false`. I know that because there I have put the `brake` in order to start the debugger

Comment: Yes, it runs fine server-side, no problem there. But on the client-side, you end up with your rendered javascript which the browser has to execute. That's something different, that's why I'm asking you to provide the rendered javascript. Anyway, if it's a sub that doesn't generate any output on the client-side, try removing the quotes and running it like <%mailFormat(EmailText%> (no quotes surrounding that).

Comment: Code always dismissed from '<%= mType%>' line. Please explain me what do you mean the `client site`

Comment: Server-side: the ASP.NET executing your code that serves the page to your browser. Client-side: that is the Javascript executed by your browser. You need to be familiar with what code executes when, where and by who. View the page source in your browser and notice that the *rendered* HTML doesn't have the server-side expressions but their evaluated results. That's what you should be pasting in this question, the rendered javascript.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42227/discussion-between-lefteris-gkinis-and-nikolaos-georgiou)

Comment: Maybe Nikolaos could edit this answer (since it is the accepted one) to include the solution that you guys found during your chat discussion. Having the solution in a chat, part of which is in Greek, is not very helpful for users who may visit this page in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You must write a .net variable(data) as a literal to use it like javascript variable. Try this

instaed of using `mType` use `mType.toString()`. See this

```
    var boolVar = '<%= mType.toString()%>';
    // alert(boolVar);
    if (boolVar != 'false')
    {
        txt.value = '';
        txt.focus();
    }
```

Comment: That's not true. When Javascript will be executed, it doesn't matter if you're comparing a "var boolVar = 'blah';" or just the literal "blah". You can write "if (boolVar != 'false')" the same way you can also write "if ('blah' != 'false')".

Comment: @Sami your solution throw me an error `boolVar` is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. And the code stops in the line `var boolVar = '<%= mType.toString()%>';`

Comment: @LefterisGkinis It is javascript function so it should not throw error `not declared` it can throw error `undefined` and this error should not be caught by .net compiler but it could be seen in console of browser.

Comment: @Sami I see this in the debugger which is `on` from the execution of the `public sub` in the code behind. The message I give you comes from there